# How to sort the output of sql data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sort the output of the echo data that i am trying to bring from mysql database. There are different rows in the table and i want to sort by one of the rows named city. But it is showing data has last in first out. The code is here:

```
<?=APP::getElement()->triggerMessage(); ?>
<div class="panel">
<?php include_once(APP_HTML.'sub_menu.php');
$data=$model->data['data'];
// echo"<pre>";
// print_r($data);
?>
</div>
<?php include_once('search.php'); ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<!-- Default panel contents -->
<div class="panel-heading">All County</div>
<form name="List" id="List" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $base_url.'delete';?>">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" class="selectAll" /></th>
<th>County Name</th>
<!--<th> Parent County</th>
<th> County Status</th>-->
<!--<th> Product Type</th>
<th> Model No.</th>
<th> Image</th>
<th> Description</th>-->
<!-- <th>Country Name</th> -->
<th>Added Date</th>
<th>Updated Date</th>
<!--  <th>Weightage</th> -->
<th>Status</th>
<th width="12%">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php


$pagination=$model->data['pagination'];
foreach($data as $row){

// echo $row['project_name'];   

?>
<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="id[]" class="checkID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/></td>
<td><?php echo $row['city'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['added_date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $update = empty($row['updated_date'])?'N/A':$row['updated_date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo APP::getElement()->getStatus($row['status']); ?></td>
<td>
<?php $fields=array('update','delete','status'); ?>
<?=APP::getElement()->getActionButton($fields,$row);?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

please help.

Comment: [sorting rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: At the  moment i am using <td><?php echo $row['city'] ?></td> and it is simply pulling data as first in last out.

Comment: ORDER BY `city` ASC ?

Comment: what syntax shall i use for order by.. as i tried various but none worked.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh update the question with exact query you are using to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `ORDER BY` in your SQL query.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: i tried using order by at various places. but none worked.